# Strange gizmo - maybe in connection with Textmesh Pro

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm getting **two crossed red** lines where I've used Textmesh Pro:
[image]

They're definitely Gizmos - disapear if I hide all Gizmos.
- But they don't go away if I unselect all the TmP Gizmos..
And in another place where I'm using TmP there is no red lines..

Does anybody know what they are (look like error/warnings...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are UI elements with negatives sizes (which is not allowed).

Often causes by using a streched `RectTransform` with lets say e.g. `Top = 10, Bottom = 10` but the parent has only a height of `< 20` → results in an effective negative height for the child.

This is not specific to TMP but applies to all UI elements:

[image]

Comment: Great answer - I'm gonna have to pay for all your generous help soon : )